# How to generate azure authorization code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to generate azure authorization code from application code without browser redirection?
I've credentials that are needed to generate the auth code that is needed to generate access token.
Is there a way to input the credentials via code and get authorization code using C# code and read it to a string variable?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client-id>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>
&response_mode=query
&scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default
&state=<state>
```

Need to pass the authorization code generate in the above code to get the access token.

If anyone can help, I would be grateful.

Comment: This is the flow that you can use for non-interactive user authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. Note the warnings on that page. In general it is not recommended. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Authorization code flow is meant to work with user interaction only. If you want non-user interaction, then you can make use of Client-Credential flow or ROPC(which is not recommended).

Comment: In my applications, there are some reports that are uploaded in sharepoint site. In order to access the reports, it requires valid access token. To generate access token, authorization code is required. I've a service account with permissions that can be used to generate the code and get access token. So is it possible to generate authorization code from application by providing credentials?

Comment: AFAIK, It is not possible to generate authorization code from application by providing credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

When I tried to generate the **Authorization code by passing the username and password parameters** it still asked me to sign-in to the account:

[image]

> **Note** that: Generating Authorization Code used Authorization Code Grant Flow which requires user-interaction. A user-agent that permits redirection from the authorization server back to your application is necessary for the auth code flow.

So, by design, when you hit the authorize URL it will be redirected to sign-in and code will be generated:

[image]

[image]

***Alternatively***, to access the SharePoint you can grant required **`Application`** Api permissions and generate access token via Client  Credential Flow.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecet
scope:scope
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

If Client Credential Flow doesn't achieve your scenario, then you can make use of ROPC flow (Not recommended by Microsoft) which doesn't redirect to login as mentioned by *juunas*.

**Reference:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)